# copy files in chef recipe is failing

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a simple recipe which is copying some files from one location to another as follows.

```
execute "download files" do 
  command "sh cp /net/adc6260022/testfiles/* /scratch/cm/test/" 
end
```

it errors with `STDERR: bin/cp: cannot execute binary file`

What's wrong with the above call?

Answer (score 2):

`sh` doesn't take arguments like that. You also don't need it:

```
execute "download files" do 
    command "cp /net/adc6260022/testfiles/* /scratch/cm/test/" 
end
```

Ruby automatically wraps it in a shell for you unless you use the Array form.